# Regular Polygon with tip on the bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I have a set of three regular polygons with six sides which I create using regular polygon from the shapes tikz package. However this always creates the polygon with the flat side on the bottom. How do I get one of the corners on the bottom with minimal changes to my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x{0}
\def\y{0}
\def\r{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dx{\r*(1+cos(60))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dy{\r*sin(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dAx{\r*cos(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dAy{\r*sin(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dBx{\r*cos(120)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dBy{\r*sin(120)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\d{2*\r}

\def\xc{\x} %mittelpunkt des aktuellen hexagons
\def\yc{\y}
\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\d cm]
at (\x,\y) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=A, fill=black] (A) at (\xc+\dAx,    
\yc+\dAy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=below:A, fill=black] (AA) at     
(\xc+\dAx,\yc-\dAy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=A, fill=black] at (\xc-\r,\yc) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=B, fill=gray] at (\xc+\dBx,\yc+\dBy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=below:B, fill=gray] at (\xc+\dBx,    \yc-\dBy) {};

\def\xc{\x+\dx}
\def\yc{\y+\dy}
\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\d cm]
at (\x+\dx,\y+\dy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=A, fill=black] (AAA) at (\xc+\dAx,\yc+\dAy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=right:A, fill=black] (AAAA) at (\xc+\dAx,\yc-\dAy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=right:B, fill=gray] (BB) at (\xc+\r,\yc) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=B, fill=gray] at (\xc+\dBx,\yc+\dBy) {};

\def\xc{\x+\dx}
\def\yc{\y-\dy}
\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\d cm]
at (\x+\dx,\y-\dy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=below:A, fill=black] at (\xc+\dAx,\yc-\dAy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=right:B, fill=gray] (BBB)at (\xc+\r,\yc) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=B, fill=gray] (B) at (\xc+\dBx,\yc+\dBy) {};
\node[circle, radius=0.15cm, label=below:B, fill=gray] (BBBB)at (\xc+\dBx,\yc-\dBy) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latex output]

Comment: `rotate=<angle>` in the node options will turn the node. Is that what you mean? Obviously that is going to throw your calculated positions off if you still want them to fit together.

Comment: Rotating the shape is easy, but they're not going to match anymore. Is that a problem?

Comment: can I just rotate the whole picture at once. I tried

Comment: You can say `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30,transform shape]`, but the labels will be rotated as well.

Comment: Is there an easy fix for the labels as well? It looks almost right except for the labels as you stated. I want them to stick together like they already do. Just rotate by 30deg and keep the labels upright.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30,transform shape, every label/.style={rotate=-30}]` But it's not gonna look *exactly* the same.

Comment: Works just fine for my case. Even works fine for all other elements that I have in the same picture but left out for the purpose of this example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`shape border rotate` is the parameter that you can use to rotate a `shape` node.
But in this case, you also need to change where labels are placed.

Unfortunately this answer will change all your code. It uses hexagon corners as reference points and also as `anchors` to place them one over the other. Hope it helps.

First example is not `rotated` and second one has a 30 degree rotation.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    point/.style={circle, radius=0.15cm, fill=#1},    
    hex/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=3 cm}]

\node[hex] (A) {};
\node[hex, anchor=corner 4] (B) at (A.corner 2) {};
\node[hex, anchor=corner 6] (C) at (A.corner 2) {};

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {
    B/1/above, B/3/above, B/5/right,
    C/3/above, C/5/below, A/5/below}
    \node[point=black, label=\k:A] at (\i.corner \j) {};

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {
    B/2/above, B/4/above, B/6/right,
    C/2/above, C/4/below, A/4/below, A/6/right}
    \node[point=gray, label=\k:B] at (\i.corner \j) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    point/.style={circle, radius=0.15cm, fill=#1},    
    hex/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=3 cm, shape border rotate=30}]

\node[hex] (A) {};
\node[hex, anchor=corner 4] (B) at (A.corner 2) {};
\node[hex, anchor=corner 6] (C) at (A.corner 2) {};

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {
    B/1/above, B/3/left, B/5/right,
    C/3/below, C/5/below, A/5/below}
    \node[point=black, label=\k:A] at (\i.corner \j) {};

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {
    B/2/above, B/4/above, B/6/right,
    C/2/above, C/4/below, A/4/below, A/6/right}
    \node[point=gray, label=\k:B] at (\i.corner \j) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Okay, here is an even more compact form using the `shapes.geometric` library of tikz:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {30,150,270}{
        \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, minimum size=3cm, rotate=30] (\a) at (\a:{1.5cm+.2pt}) {};       
        \foreach \b/\c in {1/2,3/4,5/6}{
            \fill (\a.corner \c) circle (2.5pt) node [above] {A};
            \fill[gray] (\a.corner \b) circle (2.5pt) node[black, below] {B};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simplified version for your graph.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
    poly/.style={draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, rotate=30, minimum size=\d cm},
    style1/.style={circle, fill=gray, label={below:B}},
    style2/.style={circle, fill=black, label={above:A}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x{0}
\def\y{0}
\def\r{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dx{\r*cos(30)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dy{\r*cos(30)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\d{2*\r}
\def\xc{\x+\dx}

\node[poly] (n1) at (\x,\y) {};
\node[poly] (n2) at (\xc*2,\y) {};
\node[poly] (n3) at (\xc,\y-\r*1.5) {};

% foreach for all three
\foreach \xx/\group in {1/{1,2,3},2/{1,2,3,4,5,6},3/{2,3,4,5}}{%
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \angle using int(90+(60*(\x-1)))] in \group {%% 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\switch{int(mod(\x, 2)) ? "style1" : "style2"} % choose style
    \node[\switch] at (n\xx.corner \x) {};
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

And (mainly for amusement at this end, but partly for comparison) here is a [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) + [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) implementation based on the observation that the A points form a triangle and the B points form a hexgaon.

[image]

Compile with `lualatex` (or adapt for plain Metapost).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path A, B; labeloffset := 5; u := 1cm;
A := for t=0 upto 2: (0,-2u)    rotated 120t -- endfor cycle;
B := for t=0 upto 5: (1.732u,0) rotated  60t -- endfor cycle;
draw for t=0 upto 5: point (t+1)/2 of A -- point t of B -- endfor cycle;
     for t=0 upto 2: draw origin -- point t+1/2 of A; endfor
     for t=0 upto 5: 
       fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted point (t+1)/2 of A; 
       fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted point t of B withcolor .5 white;
       label.top("A", point (t+1)/2 of A);
       label.bot("B", point t of B);
     endfor
     fill fullcircle scaled 4 withcolor .5 white;
     label.bot("B", origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```